# Sending email and notification one hour before event starts

Tags: time, .net-core, schedule

I want to send notifications and emails to event participants one hour before an event. All data about events are stored in sql server database. It must work when for example some data in database will change - start time of event will change. One hour before event I want to send a reminder about the event. Information about event start also is only in database.

I have webapi in .net core 2.1 and I going to send emails and notification from there

Comment: What have you tried so far? what has worked and what hasn't? Please take a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to create a great question on Stack Overflow, without this information most folks won't be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) to periodically go over your events and the send email if the event starts within the next hour. This would be a relatively easy thing to implement, but depending on the interval you choose might not send the email exactly one hour before an event.

Alternatively you could implement a service that will handle all creating, updating and deleting of events and then manage delayed jobs using [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) for sending email one hour before the event.

Comment: ok, i use it. it is really simple to use it, great tool, maybe u have been using it? I would like disable the dashboard authentication on server. Localhost working properly but I need to test it on server side. I have an api and dont want to use authentication to test it

Comment: what about php can someone help with sql in php for doing this with datetime? all i got so far is SELECT SUBTIME("23:00:00", "1:0:0") AS difference;